# Create a new column with sequence of column names based on sequence of dates in each row in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains a several date columns, and I need to return a sequence of column names which contains the earliest to oldest date for each row.

I.e. if the starting data is:

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1 = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),col2 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), col3 = as.Date(c("1998-09-02",NA,"2013-06-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),col4=as.Date(c("2020-04-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2000-08-12")))
```

```
  ID       col1       col2       col3       col4
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2020-04-01
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01         NA         NA
3  3         NA 2012-03-01 2013-06-01 2019-09-10
4  4 2010-06-01         NA 2003-05-01 2014-03-05
5  5         NA         NA 2000-02-01         NA
6  6 2015-02-02         NA         NA 2000-08-12
```

Then the end result should be:

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1 = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),col2 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), col3 = as.Date(c("1998-09-02",NA,"2013-06-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),col4=as.Date(c("2020-04-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2000-08-12")),seq = c("col3_col2_col1_col4","col2_col1","col2_col3_col4","col3_col1_col4","col3","col4_col1"))
```

```
ID       col1       col2       col3       col4                 seq
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2020-04-01 col3_col2_col1_col4
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01         NA         NA           col2_col1
3  3         NA 2012-03-01 2013-06-01 2019-09-10      col2_col3_col4
4  4 2010-06-01         NA 2003-05-01 2014-03-05      col3_col1_col4
5  5         NA         NA 2000-02-01         NA                col3
6  6 2015-02-02         NA         NA 2000-08-12           col4_col1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

dat |>
  pivot_longer(
    -ID
  ) |>
  filter(!is.na(value)) |>
  mutate(
    seq = paste(name[order(value)], collapse = "_"),
    .by = ID
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name, values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>      ID seq                 col1       col2       col3       col4      
#>   <dbl> <chr>               <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#> 1     1 col3_col2_col1_col4 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2020-04-01
#> 2     2 col2_col1           2020-09-01 2018-09-01 NA         NA        
#> 3     3 col2_col3_col4      NA         2012-03-01 2013-06-01 2019-09-10
#> 4     4 col3_col1_col4      2010-06-01 NA         2003-05-01 2014-03-05
#> 5     5 col3                NA         NA         2000-02-01 NA        
#> 6     6 col4_col1           2015-02-02 NA         NA         2000-08-12
```

Comment: Thanks for this @stefan. This solution has resolved my question

Answer (score 2):

*This can be achieved in a much simpler fashion.*

### Code

A one-liner `apply`ing `paste(names(sort(x)), collapse = "_"))` row-wisely (`MARGIN = 1L`):

```r
xyzzy$seq = apply(xyzzy[-1L], 1L, \(x) paste(names(sort(x)), collapse = "_"))
```

gives

```r
  ID       col1       col2       col3       col4                 seq
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2020-04-01 col3_col2_col1_col4
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>           col2_col1
3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2013-06-01 2019-09-10      col2_col3_col4
4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05      col3_col1_col4
5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>                col3
6  6 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2000-08-12           col4_col1
```

### Data

```r
xyzzy = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),col1 = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),col2 = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), col3 = as.Date(c("1998-09-02",NA,"2013-06-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),col4=as.Date(c("2020-04-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2000-08-12")))
```

Comment: Very clever use of `apply()`!  Works well in this case because of the numeric data

Comment: Meant to say works well since you can cast that subset of the dataframe as a matrix that contains all the same class of data into the `apply()` function. Also the behavior of `apply()` in providing a named vector with the colnames is super convenient. Thanks for the answer, I'm going to use this type of operation to replace a lot of my more simple rowwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

I like the pivot approach in the other answer, and it might be quicker. For these types of operations I find it easier to conceptualize (myself) to just write a rowwise operation with `dplyr`, even though using `rowwise()` can have slow performance.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Column names to work with
cols <- paste0("col", 1:4)

# Function to apply rowwise to the horizontal vector of dates
my_func <- function(vec, cols) {
  na_lgl <- !is.na(vec)
  date_no_na <- vec[na_lgl]
  cols_no_na <- cols[na_lgl]
  sorted <- sort(date_no_na)
  correct_order <- order(match(date_no_na, sorted))
  paste(cols_no_na[correct_order], collapse = "_")
}

# Apply it rowwise to a row for those columns
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(seq = my_func(c_across(all_of(cols)), cols)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```r
  ID       col1       col2       col3       col4                 seq
1  1 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 1998-09-02 2020-04-01 col3_col2_col1_col4
2  2 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>           col2_col1
3  3       <NA> 2012-03-01 2013-06-01 2019-09-10      col2_col3_col4
4  4 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05      col3_col1_col4
5  5       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>                col3
6  6 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2000-08-12           col4_col1
```